# Can't get correct value with QSettings and custom type

Tags: c++, qt, qt6

I am trying to read a small struct from my ini file using QSettings. Writing works fine, but when I try to read it back I always get the default value out of QVariant.

This is the structure definition:

```
struct CellSize {
    int font;
    int cell;
};

inline QDataStream& operator<<(QDataStream& out, const CharTableView::CellSize& v) {
    out << v.font << v.cell;
    return out;
}

inline QDataStream& operator>>(QDataStream& in, CharTableView::CellSize& v) {
    int font, cell;
    in >> font >> cell;
    v.font = font;
    v.cell = cell;
    return in;
}

inline bool operator==(const CharTableView::CellSize& a, const CharTableView::CellSize& b) {
    return a.font == b.font && a.cell == b.cell;
}

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(CharTableView::CellSize)
```

I am writing with `m_settings.setValue(Settings::TableCellSize, QVariant::fromValue<CharTableView::CellSize>(CharTableView::CellSizeSmall));`. I assume this is working fine because the gibberish inside the ini file is consistent with the UI changes. My reading code is `CharTableView::CellSize tableCellSize = m_settings.value(Settings::TableCellSize).value<CharTableView::CellSize>();` and it always gives me `{0, 0}`.

I'm fairly new to Qt and, to be honest, I am a litte confused by QVariant and all the metaprogramming stuff. Am I missing something?

EDIT: I have tried to set some breakpoints. Basically, the first breakpoint that gets triggered is the one after I've read the value from QSettings, which is `{0, 0}` as always. Then after a while a breakpoint inside `operator>>` gets triggered and the values of `font` and `cell` inside the operator function are correct. What's happening?

Comment: The answer in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144377/writing-and-reading-custom-class-to-qsettings could help.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either. According to the documentation, Q_DECLARE_METATYPE should be enough with the new QVariant implementation and qRegisterMetaTypeStreamOperators template doesn't even exists in Qt6. But the operator is working. It's just not being called at the right time, apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue! I had to add `qRegisterMetaType<CharTableView::CellSize>()` inside CharTableView constructor.